# Group means excluding individuals and having NA's

Tags: r

In a previous link:
[Calculating a group mean while excluding each cases individual value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901826/calculating-a-group-mean-while-excluding-each-cases-individual-value)

matt_k made a clever answer to compute group means excluding the individual. He propose the following:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3), 
             value = rnorm(9), stringsAsFactors = F)
df$loo_mean <- unlist(tapply(df$value, df$group, 
                 function(x) (sum(x) - x) / (length(x) - 1)))
df
```

But the code does not deal NA's properly, as it yield NA's for all the individuals of the group if there is a NA for the group.
Can anyone solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ommit the NAs before calling the function.

```
na.omit(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I shouldn't do that, I want to compute the mean of some variables by class, doing that it would imply to ommit lots of observations it could be interesting to keep in estimates.

Comment: what should an NA be counted as in your estimates?

Comment: Suppose I want to compute the mean of a dichotomous variable indicating if the individual smoke or not. I want to test if the proportion of smokers among the rest of the class is a significant predictor of individual smoking. But at the same time, I would like to use the class mean (excluding the individual) of other variables as instrumental variables for the proportion of smokers. As the example I have posted below, this imply that only one NA in the class will imply that the class mean of the variable will have NA for all the class.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple. Add `na.rm = TRUE` to `sum`.

Compare

```
> sum(c(1:3, NA), na.rm = FALSE)
[1] NA
```

and

```
> sum(c(1:3, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 6
```

For more info, see `?sum`.

Comment: Thanks but I wan a more elaborated code. I have a survey with more thant 30,000 students. There are lots of schools and classes, so I can't compute the mean class by class, I have tried to include na.rm=TRUE in the function and in the tapply command but with error messages.

Comment: @JoseJulian please provide an example with NAs and what the expected result would look like.

Comment: set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3), 
                 value = rpois(9,5), stringsAsFactors = F)
df$value[df$value==8]<-NA
df$loo_mean <- unlist(tapply(df$value, df$group, 
                             function(x) (sum(x) - x) / (length(x) - 1)))
df
1     a     4      5.5
2     a     7      4.0
3     a     4      5.5
4     b    NA       NA
5     b     9       NA
6     b     2       NA
7     c     5       NA  
8     c    NA       NA
9     c     5       NA      # It continues

Comment: I would like observations 5, 6, 7 and 9 had the group mean of the rest of the non-minssing observations of the group (this case is too simple and for observation 9, for example, there is  only the seveth observation to compute the mean.

Comment: @JoseJulian please edit your original question, comments are not designed for passing along data.